# Перегрузка операторов, необходимо иметь возможность извлечь реальный адрес локального поля

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

Необходим не указатель на управляемый класс, а указатель на структуру неуправляемого кода, указатель которого я записываю в поле класса (управляемого), далее, я хочу перегрузить оператор `&` для возможности извлечь адрес указателя, который записан в поле (не адрес управляемого класса). При этом для того что бы не было утечек памяти, и пользователи не могли изменять данное поле, которое нельзя изменять извне/внутри класса. Он должен быть единый на весь жизненный цикл класса.

Ничего не понимаю, если я перегрузил оператор `&` в библиотеке [c++-cli](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli), то почему при попытке извлечь реальный адрес указателя, значение которого закрыто от внешнего доступа *(нативного указателя `void*`)*, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) мне вдруг говорит:

> Не удается получить адрес, определить размер или объявить указатель на управляемый тип ("vlc_instance").

Пример класса:

```
public ref class SomePtr
{
private:
    void* m_hide_ptr_;
    SomePtr(): m_hide_ptr_(nullptr)
    {
        m_hide_ptr = get_native_ptr(); // Не указатель на управляемый объект!
    }
    // static // Оставим static на всякий, вдруг кто подумает что что-то не то
    void*& operator &(const SomePtr^ value)
    {
        return value->m_hide_ptr_;
    }
    ...
}
```

Неужели перегрузка оператора тут не поможет?

Comment: Если речь об управляемом коде, сборщик мусора может перемещать экземпляры классов туда-сюда. Поэтому реальный адрес может в любой момент измениться. Поэтому его нельзя получить. В общем, нужно смотреть код: что именно там делается.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Не думаю что `GC` вправе перемещать структуры созданные неуправляемым кодом на [tag:c].

Comment: _указатель на **управляемый** тип ("vlc_instance")_

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: перегруженный оператор возвращает указатель который лежит в классе. При этом нельзя его делать открытым, или добавлять методы для извлечения указателя, что может послужить утечками.

Comment: Получать неуправляемый указатель на управляемый объект нет абсолютно никакого смысла, поэтому это и запрещено. Работать с управляемым объектом можно через дескриптор или указатели на COM-интерфейсы, которые он реализует. Если вам нужно узнать реальный адрес класса в памяти, наверное нужно брать указатель на какое-то из его полей и танцевать оттуда, но не уверен, что это работает.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Да поймите же, мне не нужен адрес на класс управляемого кода, нужен адрес указателя на структуру неуправляемого кода который я записываю при создании класса.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, то, что вы хотите, невозможно.

Вы собираетесь вернуть *ссылку* на поле `m_hide_ptr_`. Это поле, вместе со всем объектом, находится в управляемой куче, и, следовательно, может быть перемещено вместе с объектом. Хотя сборщик мусора при этом и обновляет *управляемые* ссылки, вашу неуправляемую ссылку он не обновит, поэтому взятие такой ссылки запрещено.

Без ссылки код компилируется:

```
static void* operator &(const SomePtr^ value)
{
    return value->m_hide_ptr_;
}
```

(ну и ещё вам следует объявить его открытым, а то им никто не сможет воспользоваться).

Но при этом ваша цель — получить адрес поля/ссылку на поле — не достигается. Повторюсь, адрес переменной в управляемой куче вам взять не дадут, а если вы каким-то извращённым способом и исхитритесь, первый же пробег сборщика мусора превратит ваш указатель/ссылку в висящий.

---

На уровне C# вы не можете вызвать ваш перегруженный оператор `&` потому, что с точки зрения C# перегружать унарный `&` нельзя. Поэтому C# трактует `&` как взятие адреса, а брать адрес управляемого объекта [нельзя](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0208).

Вы можете, по идее, выкрутится, вызвав операцию напрямую:

```
SomePtr obj = new SomePtr();
unsafe
{
    void* p = SomePtr.op_AddressOf(obj);
}
```

В этом случае, вероятно, имеет смысл назвать использовать обыкновенную функцию-член. Но это, снова-таки, для случая, если ваш оператор возвращает чистый указатель, а не ссылку.

Comment: хм, довольно интересно, пока не буду закрывать вопрос, т.к. он все еще актуален.

Answer (score 0):

Перегрузка операторов тут не нужна. Нужен, вероятно, `pin_ptr`, в сочетании с Pinned `GCHandle` (который позволяет предотвратить перемещение объекта сборщиком мусора). Для этого придется немного модифицировать класс:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void* LPVOID ;

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

LPVOID get_native_ptr(){
    return (LPVOID)& (L"Hello, C++/CLI world!\n");
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential)]
public ref class SomePtr
{
private:
    LPVOID m_hide_ptr_;
    GCHandle m_handle;

public:   
    SomePtr(): m_hide_ptr_(nullptr)
    {
        m_hide_ptr_ = get_native_ptr(); 
        m_handle = GCHandle::Alloc(this,GCHandleType::Pinned);//закрепляем объект в памяти
    }

    IntPtr GetPtr() //получаем адрес m_hide_ptr_
    {
        pin_ptr<LPVOID> p = &m_hide_ptr_;
        return (IntPtr)p;
    }       

    //(добавить деструктор, освобождающий m_handle)
};


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    SomePtr ^ foo = gcnew SomePtr();
    LPVOID* bar= (LPVOID*)(LPVOID)foo->GetPtr();//указатель на m_hide_ptr_

    wprintf(L"%s",*(bar));//тестируем чтение
    *bar = (LPVOID)& (L"Thanks, bye!\n");//тестируем запись
    wprintf(L"%s",*bar);
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Не знаю, имеет ли какой-то смысл данный код, но он работает.

Comment: Вот так делать нельзя: `LPVOID* bar = (LPVOID*)(LPVOID)(foo->GetPtr());`. Надо обязательно сначала сохранить pin_ptr в локальную переменную, а потом уже приводить к указателю.

Comment: Но если сохранить pin_ptr в локальную переменную - то адрес будет действителен и после сборки мусора!

Comment: @PavelMayorov проблема в том, что pin_ptr нельзя вернуть из функции (тем более в C#, как хочет Yami). Поэтому и говорю, что надо сильно модифицировать код)