# Правильный каст interior_ptr к native_ptr

Tags: указатели, c++-cli

Если у меня в управляемом классе лежит не нативный указатель `interior_ptr`, то при касте его к нативному указателю на указатель на стеке *(невозможно передать указатель на указатель `interior_ptr`)*, я ведь передам правильный адрес, и в него будет записано значение которое мне необходимо получить из неуправляемого кода, которым я не владею?

Или мне придется вручную записывать полученный указатель в `interior_ptr` который лежит в классе?

Так же добавлю что нельзя отслеживать не константный `interior_ptr` дабы сформировать нативный указатель на стеке при помощи ссылки и не париться с записью в указатель который лежит в классе.

> Объект из кучи heap (член управляемого класса) не может быть
>   преобразован в собственную ссылку

Comment: А что такое native_ptr? Гуглится только что-то из F#.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Сишный указатель

Comment: interior_ptr это и так почти сишный указатель. С ним можно делать все, что обычно делают с указателем, кроме возврата из функции. Если нужен полноценный указатель, только GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Данный указатель, да, почти как сишный, но я не могу его передавать к примеру в Directx методы =) Т.е. нужно обратиться к указателю и получить нативный указатель из указателя через `GCHandle`?

Comment: Да, если указуемая переменная в куче. Если в стеке или статическая, достаточно использовать pin_ptr. Вот тут пример есть, он хоть и заминусованный, но демонстрирует это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785708/Перегрузка-операторов-необходимо-иметь-возможность-извлечь-реальный-адрес-локал/785821#